# C program help / If, Else If

Tags: c

This is the psuedocode I got for a question. The only case where it does not return D is when 60 is entered, however, any other value entered still gives the answer D. I wrote the program with this outline to verify the results and it indeed doesn't return a value other than D, or in cases where 60 is entered, an E. Why is this? I already know how to solve it, which would be by putting ranges, but I don't know why it doesn't return the correct values right now

```
for each student if student's average > 60 
    award student a D 
else if student's average > 70
    award student a C
else if student's average > 80 
    award student a B 
else if student's average > 90 
    award student an A 
else 
    award student an E
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main()
{    
    int Average1, Average2, Average3, Average4;
    Average1 = 60;
    Average2 = 78;
    Average3 = 65;
    Average4 = 50;

    if (Average2>60)
    {
        printf("D");
    }
    else if (Average2>70)
    {
        printf("C");
    }       
    else if (Average2>80)
    {
        printf("B");
    }
    else if (Average2>90)
    {
        printf("A");
    }   
    else
        printf("E");

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The error is in the original pseudocode. Was the question to fix the error in the pseudocode or was it expected that the pseudocode was correct?  Think about it; for any value greater than 60, the first condition is true, and only the first true conditional block is processed.  That should be obvious from a simple code walk through.

Comment: @ZhangQi : He should not do that at all, the correct grade for 60 is E - that is clear from the original pseudocode. The code however generates a correct result only for values <= 70.  See the posted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the order of your conditions.
Even though the number can be 92 for example, it is still more than 60 and since it checks the first condition first and the condition (`Average2>60`) is true , it prints "D".
Then it doesn't check the other conditions below because they are `else if`.

What you need is checking for `Average2 > 90` first, and then `Average2 > 80` and so on.

```
if (Average2>90)
    {
        printf("A");
    }
else if (Average2>80)
    {
        printf("B");
    }
else if (Average2>70)
    {
        printf("C");
    }

else if (Average2>60)
    {
        printf("D");
    }   

else
    printf("E");
```

Comment: Thanks. The order in which the conditions were placed had came to mind but since the pseudocode was expected to be correct, I looked for a different solution.

Comment: You are welcome :D I advice you to be sceptical about what you read, because you have no guarantee that it is true, in general. 
Also, if you find an answer helpful, please upvote and accept it so it helps others facing similar issues in the future.

Comment: Yall, re-reading the question made me saw my mistake. I thought the first condition was it being <60, not >60. Because I was thinking the entire time, why would someone get a D for getting more than 60? Something I overlooked, my bad. Thanks for the help, I appreciated it!